# Customizing members rights, without changing a roles right - .NET

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, provider

I am currently planning a project with some complex problems regarding security. With the built-in membership and role functionality in ASP.NET, is it possible customizing a specific users rights, so it differs from the the right of the roles the users belongs to?

The situation will be as follows:
The system consists of different shops. The shops has members in different roles; Owner, Manager, Employee, Accountant etc. Some general rules excists about the rights of the roles, but in specific shops, the rules need to differ from the normal rules of the different roles.

Example:
Shop ABC has 3 employees in the Employee-role. 2 employees needs the rights from the Employee-role, but the last employee has fewer/more rights than the role schematics tells.

If we add a new module that everyone in the Employee-role needs access to, it also needs to apply to those with customized rights.

I have not been able to find a answer to this situation in either the litterature about the subject or in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally a role is distinct & grants the user with that role a set of rights or privileges. I think you're getting confused with groups.

Users can be clumped together into groups for ease of administration. Users & groups can then be assigned to a role which grants them certain privileges.

So in your example, you should have a different role for each set of rights you want to assign.

**For example**

a trivial example. You don't need to use groups, but it makes it easier to assign a role to a lot of users in 1 go.

group: all users -> any user regardless of rights. the most basic group
group: newbies -> new users
group: full users -> users once they're not a newbie
group: managers -> any user who's a manager

role: standard -> base role. includes rights: access system, view orders, members: all users
role: power users -> rights: add order, edit order, members: full users
role: admins -> rights delete orders, members: managers

Comment: The problem is the amount of roles a solution like that will end up with. We have a lot of customers, with a lot of employee and many of them needs to be able to customize privileges on user-basis. Would it be right seeing the shops as groups, and users belonging to these groups?

Comment: You only need to make roles for where the privileges differ. You may end up with a lot of roles, but that's better than changing what rights a role has on the fly. I've added an example above

Comment: Makes sense, but thousands of roles sounds hard to manage. Using Groups to define a set of users, instead of roles, should take us some of the way, I guess. If we later wants to add privileges to all shopowners, we have a potential thousand different roles to modify. Only if we have a group called shopowners, and everyone in that group belongs to one and one role only, would it be possible to change the privileges of all the roles describing a shopowners rights. Sadly a user in our system, will often have several roles.